# Mounting an Arduino inside a PC

Tags: power, usb, arduino-pro-micro

I want to mount an [Arduino Pro Micro](https://wiki.keyestudio.com/Ks0249_keyestudio_PRO_MICRO_Development_Board) inside my PC, hooked up to the PC's USB.

I don't want to have external cables for this, but have it neatly cabled inside.

My motherboard has USB connectors with 9 pins (5+5 grid, 10th pin key), like these:
[image: motherboard]

These connectors would take a cable that looks like this:

[image: 9pin cable]

But how would I connect this to the Arduino that has Micro USB?

I've been looking everywhere, but 9-pin USB to USB Micro does not seem to exist?

The closest I could find is a cable that goes from USB micro to a 5-pin header:

[image: 5pin cable]

What is the preferred way to hook up an Arduino Micro with internal cabling?

Why does the 9-pin to USB-micro not exist?

Comment: why 9 pin USB to USB? .... top picture shows two USB cables

Comment: @jsotola I don't understand what you mean. Top picture is of a motherboard with 2 USB connectors. Middle pic is of a connector that would fit it. Bottom pic is of a cable that I found to be available. What is missing is a cabled that is 9-pin one end, and micro usb at the other end.

Comment: sorry, 2nd picture shows two separate usb cables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Bram, @jsotola is highlighting in the comments that the example photo you show with a 9 pin keyed  two row connector has two usb cables connecting to it. USB connections often have four wires each. The standard wire color coding is:

[image: usb wiring Colours]
(Source [Wikipedia - USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB?wprov=sfti1))

Board manufacturers are often looking for a simple way to connect multiple panel mount USB ports to the PCB and this could have been a cheap and convenient way to connect two USB ports per pcb connector.

Some suggestions:

- Research the specific motherboard online to see if a schematic or connector layout is available. It’s quite likely to be laid out like this:

[image]

- Experiment by making your own [connector](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Single-Double-Row-DuPont-2-54mm-Connector-Plug-Housing-Shell-1-10Pin-2-3-9Pin-/264226603708?mkcid=16&mkevt=1&_trksid=p2349624.m46890.l49286&mkrid=705-154756-20017-0), and use a multimeter to figure out which are the power and which are the data wires.
- If the old USB ports which used to connect to the PCB are still available, investigate further until you’re more confident about how they were wired.
- An [adapter](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Single-Double-Row-DuPont-2-54mm-Connector-Plug-Housing-Shell-1-10Pin-2-3-9Pin-/264226603708?mkcid=16&mkevt=1&_trksid=p2349624.m46890.l49286&mkrid=705-154756-20017-0) may help you experiment further to understand the PCB connections further.

[image]

- A [micro-USB breakout board](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/USB-Type-B-Micro-B-Male-Plug-Receptacle-Breakout-Module-Board-for-/192267601843?mkcid=16&mkevt=1&_trksid=p2349624.m46890.l49286&mkrid=710-127635-2958-0) may help you experiment with connections on the Arduino side.
  [image]

Comment: no need to experiment.  5th pin in micro is for otg ID: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35462/why-does-micro-usb-2-0-have-5-pins-when-the-a-type-only-has-4

Comment: Thank you! My local electronics shop had the breakout board in stock! I don't know yet what to do with pin ID, though. I think it is needed to specify which side is device, and which side is host.

Comment: I think the PC as host would be a could configuration to try first.

Comment: @Bram, checkout @Abel’s link in the comment above for more information about the ID pin.